# Creating a geographical map in R

Tags: r, graphics

I want to create a geographical map of countries in Europe where I can highlight which of the countries are using a particular system.

I have tried using the library(maps) but here I cant find an option to plot the whole of Europa (and also several relevant countries are not included in the package). Does anybody have suggestion for me on how to do is?

Comment: "map of europe r" yields this: http://www.r-bloggers.com/maps-in-r-introduction-drawing-the-map-of-europe/ What you technically need is a "shape" file of countries. Consider including "shape" in your search terms.

Comment: Please go through your past questions and check those answers that solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
library(rworldmap)
world <- getMap()
europe <- world[world$ADMIN %in% c("Austria","Belgium","Bulgaria","Croatia","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Estonia","Finland","France","Germany","Greece","Hungary","Ireland","Italy","Latvia","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Malta","Netherlands","Poland","Portugal","Romania","Slovakia","Slovenia","Spain","Sweden","United Kingdom"), ]

cols <- setNames(rep("yellow", length(europe$ADMIN)), europe$ADMIN) 
cols["France"] <- "blue"; cols["Poland"] <- "red"

plot(europe, col = cols)
```

[image]